# Contact Form 7 - Microsoft Outlook 2007

Tags: forms, wordpress, contacts

Has anyone come acrross this problem?

I have setup a Wordpress install on a subdomain. It's only temporary subdomain and is just for testing.

I've used a popular Wordpress contact form plugin called '**contact form 7**'

Any messages I submit via the test form come through fine in all but one email client.

**Microsoft Outlook 2007**

It displays the entire SMTP message in the body (content, headers, mime sections) rather than actually rending just the content based on text or HTML version.

It's strange that Gmail, hotmail, Mail (on the Mac) and Thunderbird (on the Mac) display the emails fine.

Anyone else come across this issue with email headers in Outlook?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

within contact form 7 options you have to stipulate that you want to send the email as HTML...

[image]

just tick that box and it should come throught to ms outlook just fine.